# what is the "related_name" attribute used with a ForeignKeyField Object in peewee, python's ORM library?

Tags: python, peewee

I'm trying to use python's peewee library and create some foreign keys to associate two different Models. I'm reading through the peewee documentation here

http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/cookbook.html#non-integer-primary-keys-composite-keys-and-other-tricks

where there are several points where the "related_name" attribute is used when creating a ForeignKeyField. It seems to follow a general pattern where the value of "related_name" is the plural form of the class you are creating (Tweet -> "tweets"). Is this value creating the name for the column in the table you're creating the ForeignKeyField in? How and why is this "related_name" attribute used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually have never used peewee, but from the docs and my knowledge of the Django ORM (which looks a lot similar), here's what I can tell:

When you create a `ForeignKeyField`, also the Model you refer to (the FK "destination") will be extended with a new attribute, that lets you access the relation "backwards".

In the example tutorial you linked, you can see that after the FK declaration, they can type `user.tweets`, where the attribute `tweets` takes the name you passed as the `related_name` to the FK Field.

The reason why it is usually plural is that a ForeignKey defines a Many-to-One relationship, so the reverse will be One-to-Many: in the example, each Tweet has a FK to a User, and thus easch User will be allowed to have many tweets.